# Code For Testing Speed Of Code Execution (Load/Performance Test Of Code)

Tags: performance, load-testing

Does anyone have any code that can be used to test the speed of running some code. From my research ([Performance Tool capable of testing code for speed](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/25352/performance-tool-capable-of-testing-code-for-speed), [Lightweight load & performance testing frameworks](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/8036/lightweight-load-performance-testing-frameworks)), it appears that people simply use tools to do this (JMeter, HPLoadRunner).

But, I am looking to see if there is a piece of code that can be embedded in the script to monitor the speed of executing the code.

Answer (score 2):

For more detailed performance of code I would look into [profilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)). That way you can analyse which parts of the code took long.

Load-testing tools gives you a benchmark from the outside. It can help you with comparing speed of versions against each other, but not analyse code problems.

I would try a services like NewRelic which gives [transactional insights](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/transactions/transaction-traces/transaction-trace-details). It follows all the method calls of the application and reports how long they took, just like profiler, but now embedded into the test or production environment. Run a load test against the environment and analyse the results.

Comment: Great response. But more research for me :)

I am more than happy to do this... Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your application has a CLI under Unix, you can use

```
time yourapplication arg1 arg2
```

Comment: I am running the application in LINUX (using AMPPS). So, I will check this out.

Please, do arg1 & arg2 refer to the times it took to run the code and end.. Like: https://supportline.microfocus.com/documentation/books/sx2011sp1/mgrunt.htm ?

Comment: No, arg1 and arg2 are the arguments for the SUT. If you pass different arguments, naturally, the application with have different runtimes (which does not mean same arguments == same runtime exactly, of course).